# Calculating standard error of log response ratios from standard errors of the two means

Tags: confidence-interval, mean, standard-error, effect-size, ratio

I was wondering how I go about calculating the standard error of a log response ratio from the standard error of the two means, provided they both have equal n. (I then want to use this to calculate the 95% CI, but I think I have that part down).

Note: I don't think it matters because this is a basic math question, but I am using excel because I don't have the time to familiarize myself with R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Notation**

Let $\bar{x}_1$ and $\bar{x}_2$ denote the observed means, $s_1$ and $s_2$ the standard deviations, and $n_1$ and $n_2$ the sample sizes of the two groups. Then the standard errors of the means are given by $\mbox{SE}[\bar{x}_1] = s_1 / \sqrt{n_1}$ and $\mbox{SE}[\bar{x}_2] = s_2 / \sqrt{n_2}$.

**Log Response Ratio**

The log response ratio is given by $\mbox{lnRR} = \ln[\bar{x}_1 / \bar{x}_2]$. The (large-sample) standard error of the log response ratio can be computed with (Hedges et al., 1999) $$\mbox{SE}[\mbox{lnRR}] = \sqrt{\frac{s_1^2}{n_1 \bar{x}_1^2} + \frac{s_2^2}{n_2 \bar{x}_2^2}}.$$ So, if you know the means and the standard errors of the means, you can compute this with $$\mbox{SE}[\mbox{lnRR}] = \sqrt{\frac{\mbox{SE}[\bar{x}_1]^2}{\bar{x}_1^2} + \frac{\mbox{SE}[\bar{x}_2]^2}{\bar{x}_2^2}}.$$ You do not have to assume that the group sizes are the same for this.

**References**

Hedges, L. V., Gurevitch, J., & Curtis, P. S. (1999). The meta-analysis of response ratios in experimental ecology. *Ecology, 80*(4), 1150-1156.