# What is the variance of log response ratio when adding a constant to the means?

Tags: variance, meta-analysis, ratio

Note: while I asked if is ok or not to add a constant to the log response ratio [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/335893/is-it-ok-to-add-a-constant-to-the-means-in-the-log-transformed-ratio-of-means), with this question I focus specifically on the formula of the variance of the log response ratio when adding a constant.

@Wolfgang gave a very clear and useful answer to this [similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/294121/calculating-standard-error-of-log-response-ratios-from-standard-errors-of-the-tw). My question builds on his answer: In his example, given the observed means $\bar{x}_1$ and $\bar{x}_2$, if one adds the same constant to the two means, say $\bar{x}_1+k$ and $\bar{x}_2+k$ , then is the variance of the log response ratio this?

$$
\mbox{Var}(\mbox{lnRR}) = \frac{s_1^2}{n_1 (\bar{x}_1+k)^2} + \frac{s_2^2}{n_2 (\bar{x}_2+k)^2}
$$

I am also aware that adding a constant is not an encouraged fix to zero values: [Koricheva, Handbook of Meta-analysis](https://books.google.de/books?hl=en&lr=&id=y-BjX58AXsQC&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=Koricheva,+Handbook+of+Meta-analysis&ots=_iewExC_nM&sig=QP7kP0-ZBdHodLgLYdtHFVSFEPE#v=onepage&q=Koricheva%2C%20Handbook%20of%20Meta-analysis&f=false):

> A consequence of using log-transformed ratios, however, is that the ratio must be positive […] In this case, the response ratio is an inappropriate measure and Hedges’ d is instead recommended. One should also not use a ratio as an effect size measure when either the numerator or denominator would be equal to zero; the transform is undefined and trying to adjust the values by adding a tiny fraction to the numerator and denominator usually results in abnormally large estimates of effect size.

Comment: Whether adding or not a constant is an acceptable thing was addressed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/335893/95505)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it ok to add a constant to the means in the log transformed ratio of means?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/335893/is-it-ok-to-add-a-constant-to-the-means-in-the-log-transformed-ratio-of-means)